# Where can I get the Final Fantasy soundtracks?

Tags: final-fantasy-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Square Enix Soundtracks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25173/square-enix-soundtracks)

Where can I get the Final Fantasy soundtracks? Especially the **Final Fantasy 10** songs. Also I want to have sound tracks of Metal Gear Solid, Prince of Persia, FF Dissidia.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25173/square-enix-soundtracks

Answer (score 2):

Out side of the less legal methods (which are forbidden here) I know of a [store](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dpopular&field-keywords=final+fantasy&x=0&y=0) which will sell them to you.

You might also want to look for the works of [Nobuo Uematsu](http://www.amazon.com/Nobuo-Uematsu/e/B00197I2VW/ref=ntt_mus_dp_pel) who specifically worked on 7-10

Comment: The soundtracks of FF 1-9 were actually composed entirely by Nobuo Uematsu. Final Fantasy X was the first game in the series where he was supported by other composers.

Answer (score 2):

Square-Enix has been making their game soundtracks available on iTunes for download in North America, you can see a full listing (including many of their Final Fantasy soundtracks) [here](http://na.square-enix.com/music/tunes/). Final Fantasy X can be found [here](http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/final-fantasy-x-original-soundtrack/id62445727).