# Square Enix Soundtracks

Tags: final-fantasy-series

I've downloaded the soundtracks for Final Fantasy X, X-2 and XII at [this website](http://ffextreme.com/) but have noticed that there are some inconsistencies with the naming of tracks between what I've downloaded and the actual track names (based on a few sources ie playing specific tracks on YouTube).

Is there somewhere that I can see the entire playlist as it would appear when it was released so that I can rename all of the tracks that I have to being the correct ones?

Comment: [VGMdb](http://vgmdb.net/) is a great resource for getting track listings and other info for many game soundtracks.  They often list them in their native titles along with Romanized and English translations.  Additional info includes catalog numbers, release dates, prices, publishers, and also if they are reprints, promotional, bootleg, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia has lists of all the songs in albums released of Final Fantasy games' soundtracks. For example, the ones that you mentioned:

- [Final Fantasy X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_Final_Fantasy_X#Albums)
- [Final Fantasy X-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_Final_Fantasy_X-2#Albums)
- [Final Fantasy XII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_Final_Fantasy_XII#Soundtrack)

The box on the right serves as a handy link to the others though:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that, and for answering non-aggressively. It answers my question perfectly however I'm going to purchase the tracks from a link in the previous answer for the sake of consistency and most likely quality.

Comment: Awesome. The only time I ever download music for free is when it's not available for purchase anywhere. I don't think you can download it on Amazon, but you can certainly get a physical copy with no DRM.